# Create sub-objects in an entity without needing additional SQL tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have `MyEntity` which contains the property `calculator` as shown below, and also have several other entities which also contain a `calculator` property (not shown).

This `Calculator` object contains no other properties except the primary key `type`, and its only purpose is to change the functionality of the `calculate()` method based on its type.  Note that the math is actually more complicated than I showed, but this shouldn't be relevant.

While it is kind of nice to have a foreign constraint to restrict the value of `my_entity.calculator` to one of the `calculator.type` values, I feel this approach is way overboard.  Furthermore, if I have two instances of `MyEntity` which both contain a `MultiplicationCalculator` object, both of these `MultiplicationCalculator` should be the same entity, and Doctrine shouldn't attempt to create a new one when `MyEntity` is persisted. Also, not even sure if the below will work because `Calculator`'s primary key field and discriminator field is the same field, and while I might need to make them separate fields, I am really hoping someone comes up with a better approach.

Is there another way to implement this using Symfony and Doctrine without needing the `calculator` table, and just using the `calculator` field in `MyEntity` to create the appropriate sub-object?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Calculator::class)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="calculator", referencedColumnName="type")
     */
    private $calculator;
    
    // other properties...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string", length=32)
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"multiple" = "MultiplicationCalculator", "divide" = "DivisionCalculator", "add" = "AdditionCalculator"})
 */
abstract class Calculator
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $type;

    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    abstract public function calculate(float $a, float $b): float;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class MultiplicationCalculator extends Calculator
{
    public function calculate(float $a, float $b): float
    {
        return $a*$b;
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class DivisionCalculator extends Calculator
{
    public function calculate(float $a, float $b): float
    {
        return $a/$b;
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class AdditionCalculator extends Calculator
{
    public function calculate(float $a, float $b): float
    {
        return $a+$b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your calculator has no properties to speak of, and it's only a collection of methods, needing it to be a _property_ of the entity seems a bit weird. Looks like the design is a bit suspect. What you want to do seems harder than it should because it generally wouldn't make a lot of sense. If it's just a utility class, nothing stops you from simply instantiating the appropriate one in the constructor manually, or instantiating some kind of factory that creates the appropriate calculator according to the "calculator type" for the entity.

Comment: @yivi Hi Yivi and thank you for your comment.  I agree it has nothing to do with the doctrine DB entity but right or wrong thought the logic should be coupled with the overall entity.  I will go with manually instanting it.  Just didn't know if there was some "doctrine" way of doing things.  I just learned about Separating Concerns using Embeddables (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/embeddables.html) today which is pretty cool and I originally thought might be a solution, but not quite.